# When to use RACReplaySubject vs. RACMulticastConnection?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

Using [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa), there seem to be two ways to have subscribers receive the same values from a signal, rather than re-triggering whatever operation generates those values: Via RACReplaySubject or RACMulticastConnection.

Here are the header docs for RACReplaySubject:

> A replay subject saves the values it is sent (up to its defined capacity)
>       and resends those to new subscribers. It will also replay an error or
>       completion.

And for RACMulticastConnection:

> A multicast connection encapsulates the idea of sharing one subscription to a
>    signal to many subscribers. This is most often needed if the subscription to
>    the underlying signal involves side-effects or shouldn't be called more than
>    once.
>
> The multicasted signal is only subscribed to when
>    `-[RACMulticastConnection connect]` is called. Until that happens, no values
>    will be sent on `signal`. See `-[RACMulticastConnection autoconnect]` for how
>    `-[RACMulticastConnection connect]` can be called automatically.
>
> Note that you shouldn't create RACMulticastConnection manually. Instead use
>    `-[RACSignal publish]` or `-[RACSignal multicast:]`.

Can someone provide simple **guidelines as to when you would use RACReplaySubject or RACMulticastConnection**?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually, they're not mutually exclusive, and can even be used together.

The main purpose of [`RACMulticastConnection`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACMulticastConnection.h) is to subscribe to a base signal, and then multicast that subscription to any number of other subscribers, *without* triggering the base signal's side effects multiple times.

`RACMulticastConnection` accomplishes this by sending values to a private [`RACSubject`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSubject.h), which is exposed via the connection's [`signal`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/83e23a96e726c99a444e83f306271d0e7d981379/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACMulticastConnection.h#L26-L27) property. Subscribers attach to the subject (which doesn't cause any side effects), and the connection forwards all of the base signal's events there.

There are a few different methods to create a connection:

- The [`-publish`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2171061e0511aaefc0fd19f4771a8d34ea4b5045/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L300-L302) creates a connection with a plain `RACSubject`. This subject will not replay previous values to new subscribers.
- The [`-multicast:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2171061e0511aaefc0fd19f4771a8d34ea4b5045/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L304-L307) method creates a connection with a subject of your choice. You could decide to use a `RACReplaySubject` here.
- The [`-replay`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2171061e0511aaefc0fd19f4771a8d34ea4b5045/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L309-L313), [`-replayLast`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2171061e0511aaefc0fd19f4771a8d34ea4b5045/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L315-L319), and [`-replayLazily`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/2171061e0511aaefc0fd19f4771a8d34ea4b5045/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L321-L328) methods are conveniences for creating a connection with a `RACReplaySubject`, and then also automatically [connecting](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/83e23a96e726c99a444e83f306271d0e7d981379/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACMulticastConnection.h#L29-L44) to it.

If in doubt, `-replayLazily` will probably do what you want, because it saves all values and only triggers any side effects (or starts any work) when the returned signal receives a subscription.

Comment: Would RACMulticastConnection be appropriate for the "onMessage" block of a WebSocket Client? Then, the subscribers can filter appropriately what do do with different data types?

Comment: @MaxAlexander You may want to open a separate question for that, as I don't think I can answer it without more details.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers what would you recommend to use with AFNetworking rac_GET, rac_POST... signals inside of RACCommand? `replayLazily` or `replayLast`?

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers. Is there anyway we can model a one and only subscriber at once. I simply want to model this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026927/reactive-cocoa-limit-a-signal-to-only-one-subscriber-at-once